# JNDI lookup fails websphere JRE1.8

Tags: java, java-8, websphere, datasource, jndi

I am migrating a legacy java/websphere application to JRE1.8

JNDI lookup code (below) works fine in websphere8.5.5(JRE1.7) but throws Exception in websphere8.5.5(JRE1.8)

*[Root exception is com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object.
[Root exception is javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory could not be instantiated:
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not a subtype]]*

```
        javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" + dsJNDIname);
```

I am sure, JNDI exists and valid. I tried looking up "java:comp/env/" with below code, still fails with Exception "*Name  not found in context "java:".*"

```
        javax.naming.InitialContext ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        javax.naming.Context cxt = (javax.naming.Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/");
```

For the upgrade all I did was just rebuilding the source code in new workspace with JRE1.8.
No code or config changes. Not sure, if I would require changes to web.xml or ejb-jar.xml etc

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by F Rowe, the issue is because of some of the jars within source code which also came with websphere. I was able to overcome the issue by changing the application classpath.

Comment: Hi, Yempi P. Why not simply accept the answer given by F Rowe? You gave another answer. This would be understood as an alternative solution to the question, or an improvement of the given one. Even an improvement could be better placed in an comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

See IBM support doc https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI79037.  You've likely got one or more jar files on the classpath that have versions of xerces that are conflicting with the IBM xml parser.

Comment: We got websphere 8.5.5.9. Are you suggesting to have 8.5.5.12 (as in the link)? Websphere version upgrade require approvals. I can try, if that is the only option. Classpath appears clean, no multiple jars

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you follow the "Local fix" instructions and remove the copy(s) of xerces jar in your apps or that have been added to your installation.